# Uncaught Error: React.PropTypes type checking code is stripped in production

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm on React 15.4.0, all of a sudden started seeing this error on production builds. I'm not using any of the bable plugins mentioned [here](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-react-optimize#transform-react-remove-prop-types)

Also, below are all my babel-preset packages I use.

```
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
```

Wondering why I started getting this error since last night..

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7031 does this help?

Comment: @nem035, thanks but suggestion in that ticket doesn't help me. I dont use that babel-preset plugin that they are talking about

Comment: have you checked the react version installed on your build?

Comment: Did You find any solution

Comment: Not sure, if its related but we stuck to specific react version all over the place (15.4.0) + pulled in prop-types(https://github.com/reactjs/prop-types) and got it working. There were couple of dependencies like react-dom was 15.4.2 earlier..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you're still using 15.4.0? I was good with 15.4.x, but the new 15.5.0 release did the same to my production build.

I (hopefully temporarily) locked React version to 15.4.2 (in package.json):

```
"react": "^15.4.2",
```

->

```
"react": "15.4.2",
```

Comment: Its hard to find which dependency is causing this..we just locked it down to 15.4.0 to get it working.

Comment: My React Version   "react": "^15.4.1" but i still get this Error com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: React.PropTypes type checking code is stripped in production., stack:

Comment: @SahirSaiyed "^15.4.1" means 15.4.1 OR GREATER of the same major version. Leave out the ^ if you wish to lock a dependency to a specific version. (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004)

Comment: Thanks let me check.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error as you. And I found it is external lib's issue.

`import { PropTypes } from 'react';` is deprecated, we should use `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` instead.

You can find more info here: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types

After upgrading `react-router` form v2 to v4, problem solved. Hope this helps.

**Update@2017/10/31:**
The following config works fine:

```
"immutable": "^3.8.2",  
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",  
"react": "^16.0.0",  
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",  
"react-redux": "^4.0.0",  
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",  
"redux": "^3.0.2",  
"redux-thunk": "^1.0.0",  

"babel-cli": "^6.7.5",
"babel-core": "^6.3.17",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
```